# list comprehension never ends

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, infinite-loop

This function was made for me for solving a problem in project euler, but I don't know why it doesn't end. I thought there was the "n" in the list comprehension as results, but I've changed to "x + y" and still doesn't work.

```
writable :: Int -> [Int]
writable n
  | n `elem` primes = []
  | otherwise = [x + y | x <- primes_less, y <- double_of_squares, x + y == n]
where
  primes_less = takeWhile (< n) primes
  double_of_squares = takeWhile (< n) $ map (\x -> 2*x*x) [1..]
```

Comment: `[e | x <- xs, y <- ys]` will not work if `ys` is infinite, since it will take the first element of xs and try to combine it with all of the elements of ys, and never reach the 2nd prime (in this case).

Comment: ```n `elem` primes = []``` ... Is the `primes` list infinite?  If so, then ```4 `elem` primes` would never return.  Are you sure it's the list comprehension?

Comment: @bheklilr as your comment answered the question, do you mind putting it as an answer?